# Drawing exactly 2 queens by picking a card, not replacing it, and picking another

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, card-games

What I am thinking is for part "a" to do (4/52)*(3/51) since the card is not being replaced. But the word "exactly" is throwing me off. Am I on the right track?

Pick a card; keep it; pick another card.
Find the probability of getting

a. exactly 2 queens.______

b. exactly one queen.______

c. no queens.________

Comment: Your reasoning for part (a) is correct.

Comment: Good for a) ... How about c) no queens?  That one isn't too hard either .... similar to your reasoning for two queens.

Comment: Hypergeometric; Probability of exactly $k$ queens: $\frac{{4\choose k}{48\choose 2-k}}{{52 \choose 2}},$ for $k=0,1,2.$

Answer (score 2):

First, one thing to note is that the question indicates **no replacement** this is usually a good hint for you to think about the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,that%20contains%20exactly%20objects%20with) as that is the only probability distribution with no replacement.

In general and as indicated by Wikipedia, the distribution takes the following form:

$\frac{{K \choose k} {N-K \choose n-k}}{N \choose n} $

Where:

$N$ is the population size,
$K$ is the number of success states in the population,
$n$ is the number of draws (i.e. quantity drawn in each trial),
$k$ is the number of observed successes

Applying this formula for your problem we get the following general formula:
$\frac{{4 \choose k} {48 \choose 2-k}}{52 \choose 2}$ for $k=0,1,2$

$N$ and $n$ are fixed since we are always talking $2$ cards out of $52$ and $K$ is fixed since in any standard deck of cards there is always $4$ queens.

Now going back to your main question and applying the formula, we get the following:

1.$\frac{{4 \choose 2} {48 \choose 0}}{52 \choose 2}$ since both our cards are queen we are not picking anything from the other $48$.

2.$\frac{{4 \choose 1} {48 \choose 1}}{52 \choose 2}$ since we are picking one queen out of the $4$ we have and $1$ other card out of the $48$ we have.

3.$\frac{{4 \choose 0} {48 \choose 2}}{52 \choose 2}$ since we are picking no queens and both our cards are from the $4$8 we have that aren't queens.