# probability of drawing precisely one ace and at least one ace, when drawing 4 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Can somebody help me with this problem. It should be very simple, but I just don't know how to solve it.

four cards are drawn from a standard deck of cards (52 cards).

a) What is the probability that precisely one of the cards is an ace?
b) What is the probability that at least one of the cards is an ace?

---

I'm really not sure how to approach this question. I know the probability of drawing an ace from a deck must be 4/52.

a) Say I draw an ace as the first card, then I need the next three cards to not to be an ace. So there is 48/51 chance that the second card is not an ace. For the third card it must be 47/50, and so on.
So $$P=\frac{4}{52} \frac{48}{51} \frac{47}{50} \frac{46}{59}$$

This might be a solution. But it's definitely not the way it's intended. How can I solve it in a (maybe) smarter way using the probability theorems and the binomial coefficients?

b) I really don't know how to approach this one.

Comment: Do not confuse "*exactly one ace*" with "*first card is an ace and the other three aren't.*"  You are missing the other related events such as "second card is an ace and others aren't", or third card, or fourth card, etc...

Comment: As for a general approach, look up "*Hypergeometric Distribution*"

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried looking up hypergeometric distribution up on Wikipedia, but I really don't understand the theorem and how to use it in this case. Can you help me how I should use it, and help me build me an intuition for why it's correct?

Comment: The issue is that it's in our curriculum. Our curriculum is very basic, and basically we're learning all probability theory and statistics (From discrete probabilities to continuous distributions) in just two weeks (which means two lectures of 2 hours and two problem solving classes). So I think it should be very simple and straight forward to calculate by using simple arguments.

Comment: This is what I found on wiki: $p_{X}(k)=\operatorname{Pr}(X=k)=\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}K \\ k\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}N-K \\ n-k\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{l}N \\ n\end{array}\right)}$
 Where N= population size (I guess 52 in my case). K=is the number of success states in the population (what is it in my case? 1? because I need to draw exactly one ace?). n=is the number of draws (So I assume that's 4 in this case). k=is the number of observed successes (So is that 1 again, since we only need to draw one ace?).

Comment: Yes.  So, exactly one success is $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{3}}{\binom{52}{4}}$.  At least one success is $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{3}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{2}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{1}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{52}{4}}$ or more easily written via the complementary probability, the probability that you did *not* get exactly *zero*, $1-\dfrac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}}$

Comment: This is seen via direct counting arguments involving rule of product and binomial coefficients, counting the number of good cases by first picking which of the "good" cards were selected and which of the "bad" cards were selected, dividing by the number of ways of selecting cards regardless.

Comment: I have answered a similar question few days ago, if you want you can check it out to get an idea of the general logic https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3929988/653542